# C# overload method simplification

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following routine that I would like to simplify:

```
public void SetUniform(RenderContext ctx, string uName, object value)
{
    if (ctx == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("ctx");
    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

    if (value is int)
        SetUniform(ctx, uName, (int)value);
    else if (value is Vertex2f)
        SetUniform(ctx, uName, (Vertex2f)value);
    else if (value is Vertex3f)
        SetUniform(ctx, uName, (Vertex3f)value);
    else if (value is Vertex4f)
        SetUniform(ctx, uName, (Vertex4f)value);
    else if (value is Matrix4x4)
        SetUniform(ctx, uName, (Matrix4x4)value);
    else
        throw new NotSupportedException(value.GetType() + " is not supporteds");
}
```

As you can read, the above routine is essentially the generic version of all `SetUniform`. I need this routine becuase I don't know the `value` type at compile time, but in this way I need to check its type at runtime each time I need it.

How can I reduce this routine is a more simple and performant-wise way?

---

Due the comments, I need to clarify some question that seems not enought clear.

- The "Uniform" state belongs to a specific class `ShaderProgram`, not to a wide set of classes (the ones listed on the snippet above are only a subset). Each `SetUniform` implementation access to the internal state of `ShaderProgram`, which I would not like expose, even using an internal modifier.
- The *SetUniform* overload with *object* parameter is required because I get the value  using reflection, indeed I have no idea at compile time what is the value type. Indeed I have defined an additional overload which recall specific implementation.
- Each `SetUniform` overload have a different implementation. Specifically, they call the one of the routines specified [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml).

Comment: Could you not have some class hierarchy where you can have Vertex2f, Vertex3f implementing SomeInterface. Put the SetUniform method on the interface, then have the implementations on the classes. Standard OO programming - Why ask an object what type it is in order to decide which version of a method to call?

Comment: There's something I don't understand about this. Judging by the code, this is the generic version of `SetUniform` and you have five more overloads in the same class. In this case, if for example `(value is int)`, then why would the generic `SetUniform` get called instead of the specialized `SetUniform(.., .., int value)`?

Comment: Each SetUniform calls one of the glUniform* OpenGL routine. Standard OOP doesn't help here.

Comment: @w0lf The values are retrieved using reflection, indeed I have an object value, and not a typed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a mapping between value type and a lambda that performs the required call:

```
class ShaderProgram
{
    // The dictionary is static, so that it does not get recreated for every instance
    // of the class. In this case, however, the lambdas need to know the instance that
    // SetUniform should be called on
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<ShaderProgram, RenderContext, string, object>> _setterMapping = new Dictionary<Type, Action<ShaderProgram, RenderContext, string, object>>
    {
        {typeof(int),       (instance, ctx, uName, value) => instance.SetUniform(ctx, uName, (int)value)},
        {typeof(Vertex2f),  (instance, ctx, uName, value) => instance.SetUniform(ctx, uName, (Vertex2f)value)},
        {typeof(Vertex3f),  (instance, ctx, uName, value) => instance.SetUniform(ctx, uName, (Vertex3f)value)},
        {typeof(Vertex4f),  (instance, ctx, uName, value) => instance.SetUniform(ctx, uName, (Vertex4f)value)},
        {typeof(Matrix4x4), (instance, ctx, uName, value) => instance.SetUniform(ctx, uName, (Matrix4x4)value)},
    };

    public void SetUniform(RenderContext ctx, string uName, object value)
    {
        if (ctx == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ctx");

        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        Action<ShaderProgram, RenderContext, string, object> setter;
        if (!_setterMapping.TryGetValue(value.GetType(), out setter))
            throw new NotSupportedException(value.GetType() + " is not supported");

        setter(this, ctx, uName, value);
    }        
}
```

Whether this is actually more performant would need to be profiled.

Comment: Good idea, but since I'm stick with .NET 2.0 I bind a delegate pointing to the method queries with reflection.

Comment: In .NET 2.0, you don't have lambdas, but you do have [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(v=vs.80).aspx). In both cases, however, you can use named static methods to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload your SetUniform method with the different types of value:

```
public void SetUniform(int value)
{

}
public void SetUniform(Vertex2f value)
{

}
public void SetUniform(Vertex3f value)
{

}
...
```

You could also try using the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#C.23) to avoid the null checks or define some default behaviour.

Comment: I already have these overrides, the ones called by the generic one. Re-read question with more attention.

Comment: Then why do you need the generic one?

Comment: Because the value is retrieved using reflection.